# Testing multithread situation with Moq throws strange errors

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following test code.

```
for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z++)
{
    ....
    const int threads = 5;
    CountdownEvent ce = new CountdownEvent(threads);
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            checkerMock.GetCurrentlyReleasedVersion();
            ce.Signal();
        });
    }

    ce.Wait();
    mock = Mock.Get(checkerMock);
    mock.Verify(a => a.GetCurrentlyReleasedVersion(), Times.Exactly(threads), string.Format("on try {0} failed", z + 1));
}
```

Sometimes the test runs fine on several times. It never runs all `1,000` though.

Sometimes it throws following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Moq.MethodCall.Matches(ICallContext call)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
   at Moq.Mock.Verify(Mock mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
```

And other times the following error:

```
Moq.MockException: on try 14 failed
Expected invocation on the mock exactly 5 times, but was 4 times: a => a.GetCurrentlyReleasedVersion()
No setups configured.
```

I believe it's a problem with Moq. Or is it an issue with my code?

If I wait countdown event for 5 times, it should be called 5 times, not 4. And that first error is sick.

Or is Moq simply not threadsafe in such scenario?

EDIT: this is just part of the test which was supposedly not the problem, I have removed what I was actually testing, and left what produces the error.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code here. Where is your `checkerMock` set up?

Comment: +1.  I encounter the same *intermittent* issue.  On my side, it is also a scenario involving multi-threading

Comment: +1 the question then Daniel =)

Comment: Can you add the code where `mock` and `checkermock` are defined and their scope?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Moq where recording the invocations on a moq object was not thread safe. This I believe is fixed now in some version of 4.1

Please see [Issue 249](https://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=249) and [Issue 62](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/62)